# Retrofit multiple response types

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

How can I use Retrofit2 to parse these two kinds of API responses?

Ok response (HTTP 200):

```
{
    "data": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
```

Error response (HTTP 200):

```
{
    "error": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
```

I've read tons of SO questions and tutorials, but I don't know how to do that, I've tried:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ItemTypeAdapterFactory());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(getOkHttpClient())
        .baseUrl(Constants.API_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();
```

And this is my ItemTypeAdapterFactory:

```
class ItemTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {

        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

                JsonElement jsonElement = elementAdapter.read(in);

                if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

                    // Data key
                    if (jsonObject.has(Constants.JSON_KEY_DATA)) {

                        JsonElement jsonData = jsonObject.get(Constants.JSON_KEY_DATA);

                        // Primitive
                        if (jsonData.isJsonPrimitive()) {
                            jsonElement = jsonData.getAsJsonPrimitive();
                        }
                        // JSON object
                        else if (jsonData.isJsonObject()) {
                            jsonElement = jsonData;
                        }
                        // JSON object array
                        else if (jsonData.isJsonArray()) {
                            jsonElement = jsonData.getAsJsonArray();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
            }
        }.nullSafe();
    }
}
```

But now I don't know the type to be declared on retrofit2 interface, inside Call:

```
@GET("login")
Call<?> login(@Query(Constants.API_PARAM_TOKEN) String token);
```

Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: take the raw response as your interface return type. after you evaluate the response code do the POJO conversion. I assume that success would have a 200 range and error would have a 400 or 500 range code.

Comment: Nope, the success and error have the same 200 http code. How can I avoid repeating the parsing of "data" and "error" keys and do that once for every request?

Comment: Ohh. so I would suggest to first convert the response to a JSON object. then you can check for keyword "data" or "error" to detect if its a success or an error. or another way is to simply try parsing to success inside try-catch. and parse to an error in catch block. but this would create a problem if you are expecting any list in response.

Comment: Ok, but I'd like to do that ONCE with a converter or type factory, not inside each requests.

Comment: yes, you can do that, but what you need is a constant format for error. if its yes for you then you can create a utility method to get a response type a provide you with the response as your type or the error type which is pre-defined.

Comment: My error format is constant, but sorry I didn't understand your answer.

Answer (score 9):

In a similar case, I once used `JsonObject` as type, so your function will look like this:

```
@GET("login")
Call<?> login(@Query(Constants.API_PARAM_TOKEN) String token);
```

Next, when you make a retrofit call, you keep the response as a string. So, in your java code, do something like this:

```
Call<JsonObject> call = RetrofitClient.getAPIService().login('YOUR_INPUT');
Data data = null;
Error error = null;
call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
if(response.isSuccessfull()){
  String jsonString = response.body().toString();
  if(jsonString.contains("data:")){
       data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,Data.class);
  }else{
      error = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,Error.class);
  }
}
        }
```

Here, I have used `Data` and `Error` these 2 classes. They are the POJOs. So Data can look something like this:

#### `Data.java`:

```
public class Data implements Serializable{
 @SerializedName("foo")
    @Expose
    private Foo foo; // Foo is your desired data type 

}
```

Same goes for `Error`. So depending on your rest of the code, make necessary changes. Good luck.

Comment: This way you're doing the "data" or "error" key extraction for every single request and that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I used to do something like this
**BaseResponse**

```
public class BaseResponse<D,E>{
E error;
D data;
public boolean isSuccess(){
    return error==null;
}
```

}

**Retrofit interface**

```
@GET("login")
Call<BaseResponse<LoginData,ErrorData>> login(@Query(Constants.API_PARAM_TOKEN) String token);
```

this approach will work OK when you have control over the REST API structure.
the only problem is that you need to check for success using isSuccess method for every request before using the data object.